# Resident memory behaviour in this programme?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, operating-system

I am dealing with resident memory increase problem.
To simulate that I have written a code snippet that is actually simulating my problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <malloc.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int  count = 0;
    char szCmd[128];

    system("> result_top.txt");

    while (count < 10)
    {
        sprintf(szCmd, "echo \"\nRound %d\n\" >> result_top.txt", count);
        system(szCmd);

        system("top -b -n 1 -p `pgrep a.out` | tail -4 >> result_top.txt");

        int **t = new int*[100000];

        for(long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            t[i] = new int();
        }

        system("top -b -n 1 -p `pgrep a.out`| tail -4 >> result_top.txt");

        for(long i = 100000 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            delete t[i];
        }

        delete [] t;

        sleep(5);

        system("top -b -n 1 -p `pgrep a.out`| tail -4 >> result_top.txt");
        printf("round %d finished\n", count);
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am recording the resident memory after each round and redirecting it into the file result_top.txt.
Here is the o/p from the file result_top.txt

```
Round 0

/* Before Allocation RES */
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 11736  852  724 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 a.out

/* After allocation RES */
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 15688 4808  768 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 a.out

/* After Deletion RES*/
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 14904 4028  772 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 a.out


Round 1


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 14908 4048  788 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 a.out


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 15700 4828  788 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.05 a.out


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 11872 1052  788 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 a.out

Round 2


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 11872 1052  788 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 a.out


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 15688 4828  788 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.08 a.out


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 11872 1052  788 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 a.out


Round 3


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 11872 1052  788 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 a.out


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 15688 4828  788 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.11 a.out


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
11053 root      20   0 11872 1052  788 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.13 a.out
```

Now In round 0 when i release the memory resident is 4028 and in second iteration before allocating memory it becomes 4048.

> 20 bytes increased

and after round one everything goes fine in each round.So what is the reason of this 20 byte increase?

The similar is also happening in my project code.

Comment: I'd suggest using an external tool to look at the memory consumption of your process. in between the top measurements e.g. you call printf/sprintf/system and who knows what they are doing internally. Also keep in mind that RES may not decrease until the malloc implementation decides to do so. just a call to delete() doesn't mean RES will go down.

For tooling, I suggest to use valgrind's massif or something like this: http://milianw.de/code-snippets/tracking-memory-consumption-using-pmap

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself took this code and executed.
I suppose the 20 byte increase what you are seeing after round zero is because the part of code which is not encountered yet. Therefore it is not yet mapped to the resident memory.
now when this new code will be encountered that will be mapped into resident memory.

So the 20 byte what you are seeing will increase.

To identify this you can remove the code which is encountered newly after last top recording and check the resident memory, that 20k will no loger be there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know specifically why are seeing this effect, however note the OS is not responsible for implementing new/delete functionality. The only help the OS provides is to change the total size of memory allocated to the process (typically requested via brk()/sbrk() on  Unix-ish systems).

As a result, the apparent leak you are seeing is related to the specific implementation of new/delete. It is likely these are not "garbage collecting" the unused memory until after a condition which is met in the second delete call. Until they reach this and request a reduction in the total size of the memory allocated to the process you cannot observe the memory is now free from a tool like top.

In a way this is a memory leak as the free memory is not returned to the OS as soon as it possibly could be. However, you might have faith that the new/delete implementation should release memory in a sensible manner which avoids excessively wasting memory.

In C++ you can change the implementation of new/delete if the defaults do not suit your needs...